# ruby on rails handling url parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I come from a PHP background and am having lot of trouble understanding how to handle rails handles post,get request data etc.

I have have a hyperlink that I make it go to

```
http:/localhost/clients/1/?office_id=2
```

In my controller, I tried

```
def show
   @office_id=params[:office_id]
end
```

in my view
I am just trying to display that variable

```
@office_id
```

But it does not display anything. Is my hyperlink incorrect or I am missing something else?

Comment: give us the view code. it should look like `<%= @office_id %>`, right? By the way: If you click on the link: Look at the console, it will tell you which params it received.

Comment: You console will display something like `Processing by ClientsController#show`, and next line: `Parameters: {"id"=>"1", "office_id"=>"2"}` (or maybe without the `office_id`, but I'm pretty sure it's there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I apologize. In my view I was displaying it as:

```
- @office_id
```

I didn't realize the above was just evaluating it and not displaying it.

Changing it to

```
= @office_id
```

made it work.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller :

```
def show
  # assuming you have an Office object..
  @office = Office.find(params[:office_id])
end
```

Then in your view :

```
= @office.attribute # or if you just want to display its ID then : @office.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use http:/localhost/clients/1?office_id=2, without the last / in your url.  As Benjamin said also, look at your log file to see if the parameter is coming through to your controller method.  If it isn't, then you have something else going on.

Comment: I've tested `http://127.0.0.1:3000/my_controller/2/?abc=4`. And get: `Parameters: {"abc"=>"4", "id"=>"2"}`. So this should not be the problem. I'm at Rails 3.2.12 btw.

Comment: In my? I don't have any view, I just called a URL of my JSON-only REST-API ;). But it makes no difference at all to Rails.